# Change object`s texture in real time in app

Tags: textures, arkit

Here i have the main classes. I want to change the object`s material in real time in  app but i have no success. Can you tell why please?

---

```
class VirtualObject: SCNNode {
    static let ROOT_NAME = "Virtual object root node"
    var fileExtension: String = ""
    var thumbImage: UIImage!
    var title: String = ""
    var modelName: String = ""
    var modelLoaded: Bool = false
    var id: Int!
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.name = VirtualObject.ROOT_NAME
    }

    init(modelName: String, fileExtension: String, thumbImageFilename: String, title: String) {
        super.init()
        self.id = VirtualObjectsManager.shared.generateUid()
        self.name = VirtualObject.ROOT_NAME
        self.modelName = modelName
        self.fileExtension = fileExtension
        self.thumbImage = UIImage(named: thumbImageFilename)
        self.title = title
    }

}
@IBAction func textureIt(_ sender: Any) {
     let object = VirtualObjectsManager.shared.getVirtualObjectSelected()
    object?.thumbImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chair_DIFFUSE")
  VirtualObjectsManager.shared.setVirtualObjectSelected(virtualObject: object!)
}
```

I want to change the object`s texture in app but I can`t and i don`t know what i do wrong. When i debug the app the thumbImage change but in app it remains the same. What can I do?